Can I have Visio duplicate an image on a different page
I have a schematic template I am working on, and want to be able to have an image across multiple pages but only inserted once. I was thinking something along the lines of a Shape, that I could link to from a second Shape (like ShapeText but... ShapeImage haha)
I realise you can apply backgrounds, but they would be in different positions and sizes. If I can find a way to make a Shape take another Shape's image then I can resize and position accordingly, just having trouble with the first step. Or if I could offset and scale a background page relative to a foreground, I could use that??

Create the shape once and put it into a stencil. Then drag-and-drop that shape onto each page as you need it. This will minimise memory requirements for this shape as the shape is only added to the document once (by putting it into the Document stencil) then each time the shape is used it is only a reference to the Document Stencil shape.

Thank you for the follow up :) Is there any way to change the Stencil so that it updates the image in all the locations I have pasted it? It's more a time-saving measure at this point than a requirement :D
